# Dragging an element to the right cause the original one to be shifted to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using [JQuery-UI draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) to move an element around. The things is when I drag an element to the right, the underlying list of elements gets dragged to the left!

Here is the DOM of the rendered list:

```
<div id="result" class="list-group">
 <div class="list-group" data-reactid=".0">
  <a id="sink" href="#" class="list-group-item ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-reactid=".0.$1etg">
   <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-reactid=".0.$1etg.$14dd">
    <i class="fa fa-star" data-reactid=".0.$1etg.$14dd.$1crq">Spout</i>
   </h4>
   <p class="list-group-item-text" name="Spout" data-reactid=".0.$1etg.$24yv">Data source</p>
  </a>
  <a id="forex" href="#" class="list-group-item ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-reactid=".0.$1mfb">
   <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-reactid=".0.$1mfb.$1epm">
    <i class="fa fa-dollar" data-reactid=".0.$1mfb.$1epm.$1b42">Composable type</i>
   </h4>
   <p class="list-group-item-text" name="Composable type" data-reactid=".0.$1mfb.$210d">Composable type</p>
  </a>
  <a id="read_portfolio" href="#" class="list-group-item ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-reactid=".0.$k4i">
   <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-reactid=".0.$k4i.$a1i">
    <i class="fa fa-search" data-reactid=".0.$k4i.$a1i.$mqj">Read portfolio</i>
   </h4>
   <p class="list-group-item-text" name="Read portfolio" data-reactid=".0.$k4i.$1pqw">Read a portfolio</p>
  </a>
  <a id="constituents_valuation" href="#" class="list-group-item ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-reactid=".0.$11ub">
   <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-reactid=".0.$11ub.$1r31">
    <i class="fa fa-cogs" data-reactid=".0.$11ub.$1r31.$1omt">Constituents valuation</i>
   </h4>
   <p class="list-group-item-text" name="Constituents valuation" data-reactid=".0.$11ub.$bca">Compute the valuation of constituents</p>
  </a>
  <a id="get_constituents" href="#" class="list-group-item ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-reactid=".0.$n2d">
   <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-reactid=".0.$n2d.$jho">
    <i class="fa fa-eye" data-reactid=".0.$n2d.$jho.$nn1">Portfolio constituents</i>
   </h4>
   <p class="list-group-item-text" name="Portfolio constituents" data-reactid=".0.$n2d.$1870">Get the constituents of a portfolio</p>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is how the plugin is used:

```
  $(".list-group-item").draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    cursorAt: { top: -10, left: -10 },
    helper: function (event) {
      var coords = getCrossBrowserElementCoords(event);
      var id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');
      // draw a temporary element
      dragged = $.extend({}, $scope.components[id]);
      dragged['id'] = id + '-' + randomKey();
      dragged['x'] = coords.x;
      dragged['y'] = coords.y;
      dragged['selected'] = true;          
      $rootScope.$broadcast(Config.events.add_node, dragged);

      return $("<div class='fa fa-" + dragged.icon + "' style='font-size:xx-large'></div>");
    },
    // Triggerent on mouse move while holding the item
    drag: function(event, element) {
      //TODO trigger add_node event
      var coords = getCrossBrowserElementCoords(event);
      dragged['x'] = coords.x;
      dragged['y'] = coords.y;
      $rootScope.$broadcast(Config.events.update_node, dragged);
    },
    // Triggered once a the mouse is released
    stop: function(event, element) {
      var coords = getCrossBrowserElementCoords(event);
      // if within the slider then remove the temporary node
      var width = parseInt($("#sidebar-wrapper").css('width'), 10);
      if(coords.x < width) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast(Config.events.remove_node, dragged);
      }
      dragged = null;
    }
  });
```

The rendered clone is appended to the end of `list-group`.

Below is how it looks like, Any pointer to the issue will be welcome.
[image]

Comment: Could you place your code, including JS and CSS, if any, in a working fiddle for us?

Comment: Without a working example, it isn't likely we can help you. The provided code doesn't work on it's own. [Here's a demo bootply](http://www.bootply.com/xQNWGFdsFd). You can fork that, or create your own.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it has to do with Cursor At? I think when you first start the drag, Jquery UI will move the helper element to the specified location in Cursor At, creating the illusion of it jumping left?

Comment: I can't control the position of the dragged element to the mouse pointer when removing the `cursorAt`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using `appendTo` attribute of draggable to attach the element to the #result parent, and then controlling when it is hidden or shown in `drag` function.